# Wicked_pdf Error: PDF could not be generated! Command Error: FATAL: expect 3 arguments and got: 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

Hi I am really pissed of with this gem.

I have a controller action with regular respond block:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render pdf: "Print",
    template: "claims/print.html.erb"
    layout: "print_claim.pdf"
  end
end
```

and this works well, however, now I need to use different page size for some specific pdf like envelop.  So i am trying to add the next values to wicked_pdf.config in initialize folder or here in respond_to block like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render pdf: "Print",
    template: "claims/print.html.erb"
    layout: "print_claim.pdf",
    page_size: 'Letter',
    page_width: '10in',
    page_height: '6in'

  end
end
```

or in initialize file like:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  page_size: 'Letter',
  page_height: '10in',
  page_width: '10in', 
  exe_path: File.join(Rails.root,"bin","wkhtmltopdf-to-chrome")
}
```

but this returns me error like:

```
Failed to execute: ["/bin/wkhtmltopdf-to-chrome", "-q", "--page-size", "A6", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20181224-5644-m4s0rw.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20181224-5644-3t6s75.pdf"] Error: PDF could not be generated! Command Error: FATAL: expect 3 arguments and got: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

So,  finally I managed to fix this issue by `commenting out` the whole content of initialize `wicked_pdf.rb` file.
And adding to a project `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'`. So now adding  more arguments to respond_to block works well.